# How to install PHP Extension SQLSRV on Azure App Service (PHP 8.2 / Linux)?

Tags: php, linux, azure, azure-web-app-service, debian

Does anyone know how to install the PHP extension "SQLSRV" on an Azure App Service with PHP version 8.2 and Linux OS?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please do not vandalize your post. By posting on Stack Overflow, you’ve granted Stack Exchange the rights to the content you post under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 licence](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), regardless of any changes you may make. Vandalizing your posts can result in the edit being reverted, and continuous vandalism may lead to your account being [temporarily suspended](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125268/576985).

Answer (score 1):

I could install the SQLSRV extension for **PHP 8.2** on Azure App Service running Linux with the below steps:

1. **Enable SSH Access to your Azure App Service**:

- Navigate to `Portal=>App Service=>Settings=>Configuration=>General settings` and Turn **SSH**  On.

[image]

2. **Navigate to `Development Tools=>SSH=>Go` and run the below commands:**

- Install Required Packages:

```
sudo su 
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php -y 
apt-get update apt-get install php8.2 -y --allow-unauthenticated
```

- Install Prerequisites:

```
sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev
sudo apt-get install -y libgssapi-krb5-2
```

[image]

- Download and Install SQL Server ODBC Driver:

*Note: SQLSRV extension requires the SQL Server ODBC Driver.*

```
1. curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.asc
2. curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/12/prod.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list 
3. sudo apt-get update 
4. sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18
```

- Install PHP SQLSRV Extension:

```
sudo pecl install sqlsrv
sudo pecl install pdo_sqlsrv
```

[image]

[image]

6. **Enable the Extension**:

```
extension=sqlsrv.so
extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so
```